# How do I init my object in Application instance asynchronously?

Tags: java, android

I have a messaging "service"(not Android Service) and I want to initialize it once in Applicaion's onCreate and then provide this "service" to all app componens.

The problem is that MessageBus should be initialized on separate thread, since it performes some network operations.

How do I eliminate race condition if client tries to access MessageBus instance? Say, Activity tries to get MessageBus, but it's still not initialized?

```
   public interface ServiceProvider {
        public MessageBus getMessageBus();
    }


    public class MyApplication extends Application implements ServiceProvider {
        private MessageBus messageBus;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();

            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        messageBus = new MessageBusImpl();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to init MessageBus");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

    Override
    public MessageBus getMessageBus() {
        return messageBus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add splash screen activity to your app (or show progress bar in dialog or lock your app any other way you want) and keep it visible as long as all app elements are fully initialized. showing anything to the user (especially if the init operation can take a while) is quite important as it gives some sort of feedback to the user that the app is in fact doing something.

**EDIT**

If you want to notify other components setup is done, then observer pattern ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)) should serve the purpose. I.e in your Application object your expose methods like `setOnSetupCompletedListener()` and when your setup is done, you let all your registered listeners know.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is how to notify ServiceProvider clients that init was completed.

Comment: @Mighter you can send a broadcast via LocalBroadcastManager.